# Slow Write performance in Glusterfs

Tags: ios, performance, glusterfs

I am a newbie to Glusterfs. I have currently setup Glusterfs in two servers with following options:

```
performance.cache-size 2GB
performance.io-thread-count 16
performance.client-io-threads on
performance.io-cache on
performance.readdir-ahead on
```

When I run my binary in following manner:

```
./binary > shared_location/log
```

It takes roughly 1.5 mins
log size is roughly 100M

Whereas running in this manner:

```
./binary > local_location/log
```

Takes roughly 10 secs.
This is a huge difference in time. No of cores in glusterfs server: 2, current machine: 2

Is there any way I can reduce time? 
Also, is there any standard configuration to start off with, so I can avoid basic issues like above?